# How to draw sharp curves and angled lines on Canvas in Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

The image below shows the output on the `Canvas`. Curves and angled lines are not sharp like horizontal or vertical straight lines. I have `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` on for `Canvas` as well. Please see the code below. How can I improve the quality of these curves (same as straight lines)? I am using a Nexus S. Is there a way to improve the resolution of `Canvas`.

[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBXJ5.png)

[image]

*Closeup of result*

[image: Closeup of issue]

```
Path path1 = new Path();
Path path2 = new Path();
public Paint fillPaint = null;
// called in constructor
public void createPath()
{
    //path 1 samll one
    Point[] araay = new Point[]{new Point(36,72),new Point(29,46), new Point(41,70),new Point(42,54),new Point(41,38),new Point(29,64),new Point(36,36)};
    AddBeziers(path1, araay, 72, 36);

    AddLine(path1,72, 36 );
    AddLine(path1, 72, 72 );

    AddLine(path1, 36, 72 );

    //path 2 Big one
    araay = new Point[]{new Point(144,320),new Point(109,200), new Point(171,308),new Point(178,240),new Point(171,172),new Point(109,282),new Point(144,160)};
    AddBeziers(path2, araay, 320, 144);
    AddLine(path2, 216, 144 );
    AddLine(path2, 216, 216 );
    AddLine(path2, 144, 320);

    fillPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    fillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    fillPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    fillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    fillPaint.setDither(true);
    fillPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    fillPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

}

 // add lines to the path
protected Path AddLine(Path path, int endX, int endY) {
    //path.moveTo(startX, startY);

    path.lineTo(endX, endY);
    return path;
}

// add curves to the path
protected Path AddBeziers(Path path, Point[] points, int lastX, int lastY) {

    if (points[0].X != lastX && points[0].Y != lastY)
        path.moveTo(points[0].X, points[0].Y);

    int index = 1;

    path.cubicTo(points[index].X, points[index].Y, points[index + 1].X,
        points[index + 1].Y, points[index + 2].X, points[index + 2].Y);
    index = index + 3;
    path.cubicTo(points[index].X, points[index].Y, points[index + 1].X,
        points[index + 1].Y, points[index + 2].X, points[index + 2].Y);

    return path;
}

//draw on canvas
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawPath(path1, fillPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, fillPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

[image]

Comment: When i run the code, the result looks just fine to me, smooth edges and all... Please upload a complete screenshot of the output instead of what looks like a heavily zoomed part.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using an old phone (Nexus S). Is this the reason for low quality output?
The image is zoomed just to show the issue. The original size one also shows clear distortions for curved and angled lines. My question is why do the straight lines donot show any distortion?

Comment: I just ran the code on a Nexus S myself, and the result looks just fine, as expected: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/S6jgrng.png). Does this not look like your result?

Comment: Yes, what you have posted is correct. But look close at the curves, they are not sharp. That is what I am worried about. When I have many such shapes spread over the canvas, output look horrible.

Comment: You should remove `Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` from the `Paint` constructor and remove the call to `setFlags` when you're using `setAntiAlias` and `setDither`. All of these calls does the exact same thing, so settle for one of the approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to improve the resolution of `Canvas`.

You can create a `Canvas` for a `Bitmap` of any size you like, draw your contents using that `Canvas`, and finally draw the `Bitmap` to your initial `Canvas` at a scaled resolution, in order to fit all the contents on the screen.

### Why you shouldn't do it

The screen of your device, and just about any screen in the world, have square pixels in a square grid (not worrying about subpixels). This means that lines that are neither horizontal nor vertical will always have artifacts. Using anti-aliasing, as you do, is a common technique to mitigate the visual artifacts, but they are still there.

Increasing the resolution of a `Canvas` will not help you in any way, because a single pixel on a `Canvas` is already mapped to a single pixel on the device screen.

In my opinion, you're worrying too much. When viewing the result on a device screen at a regular eye-distance, the unsharpness of the edges is **not noticeable**. When you capture a screenshot of the device screen contents, and examine it on a larger screen, the unsharpness of the edges is **barely noticeable**, and certainly not anything I would ever worry about. When you zoom in, anyone can see it, but then you're no longer expecting sharp edges.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have added the original image as well as new image with more shapes for your inspection. The image with small shapes (right) one clearly has distorted edges while edges of the big shapes are not sharp enough.

Comment: It does look less sharp when it's black on white, but I still stick to my claim that this is not noticeable on a device held at regular eye-distance. I've just tried rendering to a larger bitmap, and then scaling down. The resulting edges artifacts are far more noticeable.

Comment: I use canvas scale to zoom as well. That is i create a bitmap of normal size screen size and scale it to 1.5x. What is the best way to do this and avoid sharpness issues? create a image of 1.5x and manage scaling factor?